ASP.NET MVC Razor page local variable to controller
I am studying ASP.NET MVC and as my models got a bit complex, I am having somewhat unusual problem.
I have certain model where the items can be in different states. This items may transition from one state to another. Allowed transitions are defined in "Transitions" model/table.
To get the available transitions for particular state, I use the index page where the items are listed and add second foreach loop to the code:
    @foreach (var transition in item.State.Transitions) {
        <form asp-action="@transition.TransitionName">
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="@item.Id" />
            <input type="submit" value="@transition.Description" class="btn btn-warning" />
        </form>}

The value of @item.Id is fetched correctly for each item. However I noticed that the @item.Id is a "local variable", and the source code is id="item_Id" name="item.Id" value="1".
Correspondingly no id is transferred to the controller and I can not implement the rest of the code section, which would set new state value based on the used transition.
As I am left with no ideas what to do, any hint will be highly appreciated.

You know you can just write your own HTML and put whatever you want in the name attribute. Or perhaps I misunderstand the problem? What does your handler method look like?

Thanks for the reply. The idea behind was the increased flexibility. The "transition"s can be added later when the code is finished. I want to avoid fixed html and manual extensions each time

Here’s a POST handler that will work with the Form your Razor template generates:
public ActionResult OnPost(string action, Item item)
{
    //Seeing a request parameter called “item.Id” OR just “Id” (case
    //insensitive), the framework will create an Item instance and
    //fill the Id property accordingly.
    //
    //This is prone to overposting and you should probably not do it
    //or at least do additional validation. If your Item class has
    //a settable property called “Action” that will also be set!
    //Likely you don’t care about that, but it’s worth noting.
    //
    //The Item object will of course be incomplete and only have the
    //values provided by the request.
    //
    //If no fitting parameter is posted or it is not a valid integer
    //the framework will still call this handler and pass it a new
    //Item instance with all default values, i.e. Id will be 0.

    if (item.Id <= 0)
        return new BadRequestResult();

    return new ContentResult()
    {
        StatusCode = 200,
        ContentType = @"text/plain; charset=utf-8",
        Content = $"Congratulations, you have transitioned Item {item.Id} to {action}.",
    };
}

This model binding will work automagically as long as your Item class has

a parameterless constructor and
a settable Id property.

Otherwise you’ll get an exception.

You can use for instead of foreach. Assume that the item is one of the object of List<Test>/IEnumerable<Test>:
If your backend received parameter is List<Test>(public void Create(List<Test> model)), the frontend code should be:
@model List<Test>

@for(int i=0;i<Model.Count();i++)
{
    @foreach (var transition in Model[i].State.Transitions) 
    {
        <form asp-action="@transition.TransitionName">
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model[i].Id" />
            <input type="submit" value="@transition.Description" class="btn btn-warning" />
        </form>
    }
}

The generated html name attribute should be [index].Id.
If your backend received parameter is Test(public void Create(Test model)), the frontend code should be:
@model IEnumerable<Test>
@for(int i=0;i<Model.Count();i++)
{
    @foreach (var transition in Model.ElementAt(i).State.Transitions)
    {
        <form asp-action="@transition.TransitionName">
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.ElementAt(i).Id" />
            <input type="submit" value="@transition.Description" class="btn btn-warning" />
        </form>
    }    
}

The generated html name attribute should be Id.
